# How to surround data with an ellipse

Tags: matlab, plot, ellipse

Suppose that I am plotting different vectors of data with different dimensions in the same plot `(x1,y1)`, `(x2,y2)` and I would like to surround this data with an ellipse, one ellipse for the `(x1,y1)` and another for `(x2,y2)`. Can Matlab do it, or is it impossible?

And if this can be done with Matlab, can I also for some reasons, let one of the point of this data `(x1,y1)` lie outside the ellipse?

Comment: Would you like to enclose several data points by the ellipse (i.e. are x1 and y1 arrays or scalars)? Does the ellipse's orientation have to arbitrary? Can you give an example, preferably an image?

Comment: Yes x1 and y1 are arays. The ellipse should be parallel with a line y = ax+b, for example a=-1.2, b=50

Comment: Well, what is the equation for the ellipse? Try [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse). Rotating the ellipse should be piece of cake. If that is too much work, you find a file exchange on this on [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/289-ellipse-m/content//ellipse.m) link

Comment: Ok, thank you Patrik for your advice. I can do the  ellipse in my plot, but my problem is to choose between my data which are the best axis and the center of ellipse

Comment: You have two completely different tasks which you ask for. First to draw an ellipse around the whole data is quite easy. The ellipse equation is: `(x-x0)^2/rx^2+(y-y0)^2/ry^2=1` where x,y is the field, x0,y0 is the coordinate of the center of the ellipse and rx,ry is the radius in x or y direction. If you are able to draw an ellipse in your plot, just take `(max(x1)-(min(x1))/2` as radius in x and do the same for y. Then take `(max(x)-rx` to get x0 and the same for y direction. Now you have everything you need.

Comment: for the second task you should check out "Least square distance" or any other fitting algorithm. Your problem here is that you got 4 unknowns. x0,rx,y0,ry therefor you should try to understand and modify a least square approach for a 4 unknown function e.g. `a*x^3+bx^2+cx+d`. This ain't easy at all, but maybe someone else has a better idea. **Edit** If you know which point you dont want to take into account, just delete him (generate a tmp data without it) when doing the steps of my other comment.